# How can I explain a slower execution when perf stat does not give a clue?

Tags: c, linux, performance

My program measures the time that it takes to execute a function `500` times (this time is on the order of 14 seconds) and reports the average time per execution. Since precise time measurement is important, I took much care to get rid of all possible sources of noise in time measurement:

1. The program is run under `Ubuntu 14.04`, with root privileges, `nice -n -20`, on a shielded CPU (with `-k on` option to `cset shield`).
2. Hyper-threading is disabled.
3. Memory is allocated only once to avoid context switches due to `malloc`.
4. A large `memset` and `500` warm-up function executions are performed before the timing starts in an attempt to obtain similar state of the data caches before the timer starts. The program is pretty small, so I am not that worried about the instruction cache.
5. The time is measured as the difference of two values returned by `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`.

Here are the reported times from 5 consecutive runs (in ms, but the measured time is 500 times this time, so it's on the order of 14 sec): `28.77`, `29.35`, `28.74`, `28.74`, `29.79`. Note that there are three very consistent timing results here (#1, #3 and #4). I am seeking help in understanding and eliminating the source of the outliers. Here is the report of `perf stat` for the first and the last runs:

First run:

```
    29176.113027 task-clock (msec)         #    0.999 CPUs utilized          
               596 context-switches          #    0.020 K/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
             5,061 page-faults               #    0.173 K/sec                  
   104,825,303,791 cycles                    #    3.593 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   104,316,069,689 instructions              #    1.00  insns per cycle        
    19,672,922,035 branches                  #  674.282 M/sec                  
       346,005,888 branch-misses             #    1.76% of all branches
```

Last run:

```
      30003.678991 task-clock (msec)         #    0.999 CPUs utilized          
               417 context-switches          #    0.014 K/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
             4,945 page-faults               #    0.165 K/sec                  
   107,799,951,303 cycles                    #    3.593 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   104,310,601,483 instructions              #    0.97  insns per cycle        
    19,671,642,624 branches                  #  655.641 M/sec                  
       345,885,486 branch-misses             #    1.76% of all branches        

      30.023661486 seconds time elapsed
```

I do not notice anything in these stats that would give a clue as to why the last run is slower than the first one. I will very much appreciate any help in this.

EDIT: it was noticed that the Instructions per Cycle number is different. It would be great to get to the root cause of this difference.

Comment: I have to say - this looks a little like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish by getting some code to run at exactly the same speed? But I think your timing differential will be that instructions per cycle number.

Comment: How much memory is your function using?  Does it depend on anything else?  Have you tried `mlock`ing it?

Comment: To answer the question of Sobrique. The function (which performs A* search) has a parameter and I need to establish the value of that parameter that makes the function run the fastest. Since the function  takes a while to solve interesting problems, I need to use a smart method (such as gradient descent) to find the best value of the parameter by as few runs as possible. I need reliable time measurement to enable such a method (e.g. to compute discrete derivatives).

Comment: The function uses about 130 MB, of which only 10 MB are generated in the function. I allocate a 16 MB chunk before the first function execution and re-use that same chunk for all 500 executions. As for `mlock` ing, please note that the longer execution actually had fewer page faults.

Comment: After more thought: how can there be page faults in my program? It uses only 130 MB memory on a system with 32 GB installed, so why would a page ever be swapped out of the physical memory? In any case, I tried doing `mlockall(MCL_FUTURE)` at the beginning of the program. The number of page faults went down to 240 (how come these remained?). Most strangely, the Instructions per Cycle went down to 0.96 and only rarely goes up to 0.99. So, how come locking memory slowed the program down? The time measurements did become more consistent, so I am optimistic.