# How can I force consistent cache behavior for the same memory access pattern?

Tags: c, performance, caching, memory

My program allocates a chunk of 16 MB of memory and proceeds by performing a CPU-bound computation (A* search) that uses only that pre-allocated memory. When I `perf stat -e cache-references,cache-misses` this program, I sometimes get significantly different counts (e.g. `19%` vs. `20%`) of cache misses between the different executions despite the fact that the memory access pattern of these executions is identical.

I tried to warm up the cache in two ways:

1. Putting the main computation inside a loop.
2. Running various loops that access the allocated memory in various patterns.

However, I still do not get better consistency. After much effort (described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/582356/can-i-get-a-100-dedicated-cpu-to-my-critical-process and [How can I explain a slower execution when perf stat does not give a clue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325905/how-can-i-explain-a-slower-execution-when-perf-stat-does-not-give-a-clue)), my program suffers from very few context switches and consistency of cache behavior seems to be the only thing that separates me from getting consistent timings.

EDIT 1: One more relevant detail. When I put the computation in a loop and measure the time that each iteration takes, the timings of the different iterations within the same execution are extremely consistent (within 0.02 seconds on a computation that takes about 6 seconds). However, a different execution may show a different (by as much as 0.3 seconds) timing, while again the time that the different iterations within that new execution take would be consistent.

EDIT 2: I also forgot to mention that the 16 MB chunk is locked in memory.

Comment: "Very few context switches" != 0. Are you sure that's not a relevant factor?

Comment: After `perf stat`ing the program many times, I am pretty sure that the `time` is directly proportional to the cache miss rate. As for the context switches, there are only `four` of them in `six` seconds and `htop` shows that nothing else runs on the CPU. Also, if context switches were a relevant factor, then wouldn't I get different timings for the loop iterations when I put the computation into the loop?